# Isomorphism class of vector bundle over $\mathbb S^1$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, vector-bundles

I'm currently self-studying through the book Differential forms in Algebraic Topology by Bott & Tu and got stuck on an exercise 6.10, which asks to compute $\textrm{Vect}_k(\mathbb S^1),$
the isomorphism classes of rank $k$ vector bundles over $\mathbb S^1$. I've gotten the result for $k=1$, which was simple since $O(1)\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, however, I'm not sure how to generalize to higher-rank vector bundles. Since the circle is a 1-manifold, it seems like the classification of higher vector bundles should be able to be deduced from the $k=1$ case. Is this true? If so, how? Any hints would be appreciated.

EDIT: I apologize, should've been more detailed about the $k=1$ argument. given a basic open cover $\{U,V\}$ of $S^1$ since $U\bigcap V$ is just two disconnected intervals, there will be four possibe cocycles (with values in $O(1)$). Similarly, there are very few possible transition functions between the cocycles so its easy to compute that these transition functions partition the four possible cocyles into two groups of two, one of which clearly corresponds to the product bundle and so the other must correspond to the isomorphism class of the Mobius bundle.

Comment: How do you get the $k=1$ case?

Comment: It is impossible for us to tell you how to generalize the argument you used for $k=1$ for higher ranks if you do not tell us what the argument is!

Comment: Line bundles can be classified directly by the Stiefel-Whitney (the real case) or Chern class (the complex case). For the higher ranks, consider the induced clutching map and reduce the problem to one of homotopy. You can also use the CW-structure of $S^n$ to pull of a trivial bundle from an arbitrary high-dimensional bundle $\xi \to S^n$. Both methods work in higher dimensions.

Comment: @anomaly, it is very unlikely that your comment is of any help: do you think that the OP will know what a characteristic class is or be familiar with the clutching construction, based on the question?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: The OP has access to Bott & Tu and Wikipedia. What's wrong with pointing him toward the standard tools for this sort of problem, especially since he's self-studying?

Comment: @juan, there are many cocycles, in fact: they need not be constant in the components of that intersection!

Comment: @anomaly, I figure that the answer can be obtained using characteristic classes, K-theory, or something fancy like that, but this material isn't covered until towards the end of Bott & Tu while the question is asked in the first chapter. So there must be a way of classifying these vector bundles without using this fancy stuff.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez but how can they not be constant in the components of the intersection if each component is a connected open interval and we want a continuous function into a two point space?

Comment: Well, I mean in general...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

$\require{AMScd}$Consider the map $f:t\in[0,1]\mapsto\exp(2\pi it)\in S^1$. If $E$ is a vector bundle in $S^1$, then $f^*(E)$ is a vector bundle on $[0,1]$. It is not difficult to show that all vector bundles on $[0,1]$ are trivial. You can see from this that there is a continuous bundle map $F$ such that the diagram
\begin{CD}
[0,1]\times\mathbb R^n @>F>> E \\
@Vp_2VV @V\xi VV \\
[0,1] @>f>> S^1
\end{CD}
commutes and $F$ is an isomorphism on fibers. In particular, we can construct a unique linear isomorphism $\phi_f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ such that $F(1,\phi_f(v))=F(0,v)$ for all $v\in\mathbb R^n$.

Deduce from this that all vector bundles on $S^1$ are obtained from a trivial vector bundle $[0,1]\times\mathbb R^n\to[0,1]$ by identifying $(0,v)$ with $(1,\phi(v))$ for a fixed automorphism $\phi:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$.

Next, show that if $\phi$ and $\psi$ are two automorphisms of $\mathbb R^n$ in the same path component of $GL(n,\mathbb R)$, then the correspinding bundles are isomorphic.

Comment: Could you explain why the last statement, "if $\phi$ and $\psi$ are two automorphisms ~ then the corresponding bundles are isomorphic" holds?

Comment: @user124697 For a path $\phi_t$ with $\phi_0=\phi$ and $\phi_1=\psi$, one can define the isomorphism as $(v,t) \to (\phi_t \circ \phi^{-1}(v),t)$.

Comment: Might be a silly question, but why is $\phi_f$ enough to determine the vector bundle? (I understand it intuitively, but I'm having trouble proving it.)