# Path homotopy and vector bundle isomorphism

Tags: differential-topology, vector-bundles

[Isomorphism class of vector bundle over $\mathbb S^1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2597280/isomorphism-class-of-vector-bundle-over-mathbb-s1)

In the answer to this question, it is written that

> if $\phi$ and $\psi$ are two automorphisms of $\mathbb R^n$ in the same path component of $GL(n,\mathbb R)$, then the corresponding bundles are isomorphic.

Could you explain why this holds?

> EDIT: I tried to give my own answer; suppose $\{U,V\}$ is an (canonical) open cover of $S^{1}$ and $U$ contains $1 \in S^{1}$, the glued point in $E$. Then, if two total space is isomorphic as a vector bundle, then their cocycles $\{g_{UV}\}$ and $\{g_{UV}'\}$ has the relationship
>   $$g_{UV}' = \lambda_{U}g_{UV}\lambda_{V}^{-1}.$$
>
> Now since $U \cap V$ has two connected component, with homeomorphism $\{\phi_{U},\phi_{V}\}$ and $\{ \phi_{U}',\phi_{V}'\}$ for each vector bundles, we should have $$\phi_{U}' = \lambda_{U}\phi_{U}, \phi_{V}' = \lambda_{V}\phi_{V}.$$
>   Note that $\lambda_{V}$ is just identity matrix for any $x \in V$; we should investigate $\lambda_{U}$ only. Then, $$\lambda(x)\begin{cases} \in GL(n,\mathbb{R})^{+}& \text{ if } x \in [0,1/2)\times \mathbb{R}^{n} \\ \in GL(n,\mathbb{R})^{-}& \text{ if } x \in (1/2,1]\times \mathbb{R}^{n}\end{cases}$$ 
>   However, $\lambda(x)$ should be continuous map, thus such $\lambda_{U}$ doesn't exist.

Is my answer correct?